# Android:How do I disable checkbox in a listview based on some condition

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I have a customized list-view and each row of the list-view contains a check box and a text field. Clicking on any check-box in any row of the list-view should disable other check-boxes.How to achieve this.

Comment: check here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844061/android-how-do-i-enable-disable-a-checkbox-depending-on-a-radio-button-being-s

Answer (score 0):

declare an array list of checkbox.
Inside your custom adapter in getView method :

put checkbox inside an arraylist.

```
 if(your condition==true) {

    for(CheckBox c: lsitOfCheckBox){
        c.setEnabled(false);
    }

 }
```

Comment: But if I do this then it ill disable only the check box which I have clicked. I want to disable other check boxes in the list if check box of any row is clicked

Comment: Updated answer may help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your custom adapter in getView method :

```
if(your condition==true){
      checkBox.setEnabled(false);
} else {
      checkBox.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use recycler view, it is way better and practical than listview.

To-do that you need to have a custom adapter class which is extended from BaseAdapter.

You need have a List list for your adapter to iterate over. And in your custommodel you need to add new field called `private boolean selected'`.

Then you need to define onclick listeners for the checkbox in the `getview()` method of the adapter.

Then in the `onclicklistener.onclick` method you should get the position of the clicked item. And iterate over all your data and set `'item.selected = false;'`
and only set `list[clickPosition].selected = true;`

Then call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

I hope it is clear for you, if not post some more data.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd suggest using a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), I'll answer the question for a ListView, but really either way the solutions will be similar.

Assuming you're using the [ViewHolder pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) in your BaseAdapter. Inside your getView function set a onCheckedChangedListener and inside that create a function that sets an `isListChecked` boolean inside the class that implements your adapter's Interface for `setListChecked`, should look something like:

```
cbListItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           myInterface.setListChecked(isChecked);
           notifyDatasetChanged();
       }
   }
);
```

Inside getView you will also need to check the `isListChecked` boolean and set that as the CheckBox state